# Some indexes may not have been recreated

Tags: database, db2, warnings, database-indexes, reorganize

Hitting `SQL1279W  Some indexes may not have been recreated.` when I am trying to reorg a huge table in `db2`.

Will `db2` auto rebuild it? How we can know how long time the rebuild need to be done.

Any ideas to solve this?

I saw something as follow in

```
2018-03-09-02.46.15.407340+480 E379842220A543       LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 9699328              TID : 61242          PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000           DB   : MYDB
APPHDL  : 0-37047              APPID: 10.0.0.15.49659.180309024549
AUTHID  : EDW2CBDB             HOSTNAME: myweb.com.my
EDUID   : 61242                EDUNAME: db2agent (MYDB) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, data management, sqldBeginIndexCreate, probe:1
MESSAGE : ADM5540W  Rebuilding "2" indexes on table "ADM  .CORPORATELOGS".
```

Comment: Have you tried looking up the warning code in the manual? It has at least some information that you are requesting.

Comment: hi @mustaccio, I just add in some log in db2diag.log , do you know which 1 is the warning code?

Comment: It's right there in your question: SQL1279W

Answer (score -1):

REORG of a table reorganizes the data in the base table and then rebuilds the indexes for that table. If the process is interrupted, you might get this error.

IBM support for Offline reorg shows some of the diagnostic messages that might indicate an interrupt.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21432401

REORG INDEXES will rebuild the indexes for a given table.